# How does IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName] work in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo

I've always implemented the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) interface without actually wondering what this line means and how it works.

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
    get { return this.GetValidationError(propertyName); }
}
```

How does `.this[string propertyName]` work, and when/how does this property get called?

Comment: I _think_ this is [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) of an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) and it would be called whenever you have an explicitly typed `IDataErrorInfo` object where you write: `string myPropertyError = myDataErrorInfo["SomePropertyName"];`

Comment: Yup, it's just explicit interface implementation. Are you aware of that in general? (If not, just look it up.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have a rough idea of what it means to implement an interface explicitly (I [asked](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/136319/1130) on Programmers.SE about that a while back), but the `.this[string propertyName]` was the main part I didn't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this[key]` is in fact an indexer, and is somewhat of a cross between a property and a method. It acts like a property since you can bind to it, but as opposed to regular properties, it receives a parameter.

Behind the scenes it's implemented as a method - `get_Item(key)`, and if you'd want to access it via reflection you'd need to use `Item` for a name. For example:

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Item");
```

This is also important to know when implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, in which case, `"Item[]"` or `Binding.IndexerName` should be used as a property name in order to update the UI.

Answer (score 8):

This is [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx) of an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx). (EDIT: The `IDatatErrorInfo.` part of the signature signifies the explicit interface implementation, and the `.this[...]` part signifies an indexer.)

It would be called whenever you have an explicitly typed `IDataErrorInfo` object and you use square brackets on it to retrieve/get a value while passing a string in. For example:

```
IDataErrorInfo myDataErrorInfo = GetErrorInfo();
string myPropertyError = myDataErrorInfo["SomePropertyName"];
```

Note that since it's an explicit interface implementation, it will only be accessible when the type is known *exactly* as an `IDataErrorInfo`. If you have it typed as your subclass, it won't be accessible unless that class exposes it:

```
MyDataErrorInfoImpl myDataErrorInfo = GetErrorInfo();
string myPropertyError = myDataErrorInfo["SomePropertyName"]; //compiler error!
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear in my post. I was more interested in finding out how `.this[string propertyName]` works, which you mentioned was an indexer. I'm looking that up now :) I do understand implicit vs explicit interfaces.

Comment: @Rachel Ahh, I've edited my answer to be clear which part of the signature refers to the explicit interface implementation and the indexer. EDIT: Indexers essentially let you implement array-style square bracket syntax but let you use any type besides just `int`. They behave just like properties/methods and follow the same rules for overloading/overriding/new/virtual/abstract/etc.

Comment: Thank you. I was having trouble googling variations of  *"what does .this[string propertyName] mean"* to come up with what it actually is. Now that I know it's referred to as an indexer, I am having a much easier time finding material about it :)